# How use maven profiles in mule domain project?

Tags: maven, mule, maven-profiles

My target is : use maven profile in mule 3.6.1 domain project.

I have a maven profile configuration that works fine for any java maven project. I use this configuration for my mule projects:

```
<project ...>

    <modelVersion>
    <groupId>
    <artifactId>
    <version>
    <packaging>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${resource.dir}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>env1/</exclude>
                    <exclude>env2/</exclude>
                    ...
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>env1</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target.env1</name>
                    <value>env1</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <resource.dir>env1</resource.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>env2</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target.env2</name>
                    <value>env2</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <resource.dir>env2</resource.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile> ...
    </profiles>

</project>
```

directory structure:

```
my_maven_mule_project\
my_maven_mule_project\pom.xml
my_maven_mule_project\src\
my_maven_mule_project\src\app
my_maven_mule_project\src\app\my_mule_config.xml
my_maven_mule_project\src\app\mule-app.properties
my_maven_mule_project\src\app\mule-deploy.properties
my_maven_mule_project\src\java
my_maven_mule_project\src\resources
my_maven_mule_project\src\resources\env1
my_maven_mule_project\src\resources\env1\prop.properties
my_maven_mule_project\src\resources\env2
my_maven_mule_project\src\resources\env2\prop.properties

after maven profile execution : mvn clean package -Penv1 , zip artifact has:

my_mule_config.xml
mule-app.properties
mule-deploy.properties
lib
classes
classes\prop.properties
```

classes\prop.properties only has env1 parameters and this is good for me!

But when I tried with mule domain project does not work. Result of maven execution has all folder with all properties environments:

```
my_mule_domain_project\env1
my_mule_domain_project\env1\prop.properties
my_mule_domain_project\env2
my_mule_domain_project\env2\prop.properties
my_mule_domain_project\mule-deploy.properties
my_mule_domain_project\mule-domain-config.xml
my_mule_domain_project\prop.properties
my_mule_domain_project\lib
```

And this is not good for me.

Mule domain project :

https://github.com/jrichardsz/mule-esb-usefull-templates/tree/master/my_mule_domain_project

So, Does anyone have any maven configuration to use profiles in a mule **domain** project?

I can't find anything in mule official documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug (a very ugly one) in mule-domain-maven-plugin, it packages the src directory instead of the target, causing this kind of problems. Your resource configuration works changing things in target directory (that is how Maven is supposed to work) and because domain plugin packages src directory the source filtering is not applied. 
You can file a JIRA ticket here: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE
I cannot find a good way to fix it except that packaging your domain by using maven-assembly-plugin... sorry about that.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your explanation. Is there a way to fix this plugin ? git repo?. I have some time to have fun with this plugin and maybe make a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately it was not necessary to modify the plugin :S

Thanks to the Explanation of Ale and some tests , adding this line works :)

```
<resourcesDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</resourcesDirectory>
```

Final pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_mule_domain_project</artifactId>
    <packaging>mule-domain</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Domain my_mule_domain_project Project</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-domain-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                <copyToDomainsDirectory>false</copyToDomainsDirectory>
                <resourcesDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes</resourcesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${resource.dir}</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>env1/</exclude>
                    <exclude>env2/</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>env1</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target.env1</name>
                    <value>env1</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <resource.dir>env1</resource.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>env2</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>target.env2</name>
                    <value>env2</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <resource.dir>env2</resource.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

A project that could be used as a template is here:

https://github.com/jrichardsz/mule-esb-usefull-templates/tree/master/my_mule_domain_project-fix-maven-profile

Regards